# Suggest the best software stack for a large buyer/supplier portal

Tags: e-commerce, lamp, multisite, portal, enhanced-ecommerce

I am working with a company that prints construction logos on large banners to place on the construction site. They do about 5 million in business per year with 7 large accounts that have 200-300 store locations. The store can order a banner from their personalized site with their personalized color choices and logos.

What bogs workflow down: when our banner suppliers switch colors, sizes, or color names, our 7 buyer websites need to reflect the update across the board. We don't use APIs from the suppliers, though a few of them offer it - our developers need to manually make these changes in the database, which can take days.

We are currently using a LAMP stack with a server on site. Our warehouse management software is AngularJS, but as you can imagine is extremely finicky. We spend more time patching all of the old issues than coding the future system that will be able to support our needs.

What are other people using to accomplish the same type of multi-site personalization for a buyer/supplier portal that has 3,000 user accounts?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.